# How can I upload a file named after a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I have a very basic file uploading script, inside a form.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
<input type="image" src="save.jpg" />
```

Which executes the following PHP code:

```
include 'db.php';

$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$target = "uploads/".$file;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
  echo "<strong>Success:</strong> File uploaded";
} 
else
{
  echo "<strong>Error:</strong> Could not upload file";
}
```

What I would like to do is skip the process in which you open windows explorer to specify a file location and instead, upload a file named after a PHP variable. The PHP variable contains an email address, which is also the name of the file stored on my local machine.

Comment: You can't do that. If you could you could just upload any arbitrary files from user machine without the user ever knowing it.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to speed up the process of selecting the name of a file that the system already knows?

Comment: Well not really, the user has to select the file himself, otherwise it's a security breach.

Comment: i think it is not safe way too how can system knows the file unless users select his choice

Comment: thats why this is UPLOADED file

Comment: As much as you can skip complete Upload process and Push manually file to a Special FTP Server, Then use PHP FTP Functions to copy file to your server.

Comment: When I create an invoice for a customer, it is saved as their email address. When a user logs into my website, I know their email address. If I click a button that says "Upload Invoice" on their profile then I was hoping the system could automatically upload the file on my local machine that matches that email.

Comment: You should use your customer's email variable and integrate it into your uploaded file's name; that's what I use. @CraigyCraigo